# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'MakeCellsEditable' of undefined' error

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatables plugin in my project and I'm using a free [cellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit). Since I applied it I've added this error `Cannot read property 'MakeCellsEditable' of undefined`. I tried to add a `table.MakeCellsEditable('destroy');` like in this [post](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/issues/6#issuecomment-500429096) but it doesn't work.

HMTL script :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/DataTables/dataTables.altEditor.free.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/DataTables/dataTables.cellEdit.js') }}"></script>
```

JS :

```
var table;

table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "createdRow" : function ( row, data_use, dataIndex ) {
        $(row).attr('id', 'line-' + dataIndex);
    },
    'columnDefs' : [{
        'targets': "_all",
        'createdCell' : function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              $(td).attr('id', 'cell-' + col);
         }
    }],
    data : data_use,
    columns : column_name,
    dom : 'Bfrtip',
    select : 'single',
    responsive : true,
    altEditor : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: true,
    buttons : [{
        extend : 'selected',
        text : 'Edit',
        name : 'edit'
    }],
});

table.MakeCellsEditable({
       "onUpdate" : myCallbackFunction,
});

function myCallbackFunction (updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
        console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
        console.log("The old value for that cell was: " + oldValue);
        console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
}
```

**Solution:**

In my project the table is display when I click on a button so the `table` variable is not yet created, to solve this problem I added this s :

```
$("#datatable").on("click", function () {
    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate" : myCallbackFunction,
        "columns" : [2],
        "inputTypes" : [{
            "column" : 2,
            "type" : "number",
            "option" : null,
        }],
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? On `table.MakeCellsEditable({"onUpdate" : myCallbackFunction,});`? If so, it says that `table` is undefined. Can you create working demo demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @barbsan Yes the error is on this lin : `Cannot read property 'MakeCellsEditable' of undefined`

Comment: Is this whole js code in one `<script>` tag? Do you have element with id="datatable" in your HTML? Without more info I can only say that `table` is undefined. Repeating error message won't help much.

Comment: @barbsan my code it's work but I would like to add a inline editor for my table and when I try to add it I have this error.

Comment: Could you show order of `<script>` tags with libraries? `myCallbackFunction` is irrelevant here. `$('#datatable').DataTable({/*options*/})` should assign `table` with DataTable instance, but it remains undefined

Comment: @barbsan I add all of script I use in the post.

Comment: I've adapted some found jsfiddle to your code, take a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/106z9ygs/ maybe you'll find what's missing in your code

Comment: @barbsan I'm stupid when I write the code I forgot to add the condition when I click on the table. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197860/discussion-between-barbsan-and-sebcollard).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$('#datatable').DataTable({...})` does not work. Did you add datatbles plugin into project via html or js?

Comment: All of JS I use is include in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused if the library was not correctly imported. 
Try `console.log(table)` to make sure that it was correctly imported.